# Swagger Parser error duplicated mapping key

Tags: api, yaml, swagger, backend

**Hi friends, I have an error during yaml API testing in Swagger editor**

- I have duplicate mapping key error in line no 98
- I try to force execute the testing I have :

Failed to fetch.
Possible Reasons:

CORS

Network Failure
URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.          ----- this error please help me!!..

```
 openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: 06-jobs-api
  contact: {}
  version: '1.0'
servers:
- url: https://new-jobs-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1
  variables: {}
paths:
  /auth/register:
    post:
      tags:
      - Auth
      summary: register
      operationId: register
      parameters: []
      requestBody:
        description: ''
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/registerrequest'
            example:
              name: josh
              email: josh@gmail.com
              password: joshgmail.com
        required: true
      responses:
        '200':
          description: ''
          headers: {}
      deprecated: false
      security: []
  /auth/login:
    post:
      tags:
      - Auth
      summary: login
      operationId: login
      parameters: []
      requestBody:
        description: ''
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/loginrequest'
            example:
              email: john@gmail.com
              password: john@gmail.com
        required: true
      responses:
        '200':
          description: ''
          headers: {}
      deprecated: false
      security: []
  /jobs:
    post:
      tags:
      - Jobs
      summary: create job
      operationId: createjob
      parameters: []
      requestBody:
        description: ''
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/createjobrequest'
            example:
              company: mongodb
              position: back-end developer
        required: true
      responses:
        '200':
          description: ''
          headers: {}
      deprecated: false
    get:
      tags:
      - Jobs
      summary: get all jobs
      operationId: getalljobs
      parameters: []
      responses:
        '200':
          description: ''
          headers: {}
      deprecated: false
    /jobs/{id}:
    parameters:
      - in: path
        name: id
        schema:
          type: string
        required: true
        description: The user ID
    get:                      ----- here I have an error line no 98
      tags:
      - Jobs
      summary: get single job
      operationId: getsinglejob
      parameters: []
      responses:
        '200':
          description: ''
          headers: {}
      deprecated: false
   
    patch:
      tags:
      - Jobs
      summary: update job
      operationId: updatejob
      parameters: []
      requestBody:
        description: ''
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/updatejobrequest'
            example:
              company: prime
              position: front-end developer
        required: true
      responses:
        '200':
          description: ''
          headers: {}
      deprecated: false
    delete:
      tags:
      - Jobs
      summary: delete job
      operationId: deletejob
      parameters: []
      responses:
        '200':
          description: ''
          headers: {}
      deprecated: false
components:
  schemas:
    registerrequest:
      title: registerrequest
      required:
      - name
      - email
      - password
      type: object
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
        email:
          type: string
        password:
          type: string
      example:
        name: josh
        email: josh@gmail.com
        password: joshgmail.com
    createjobrequest:
      title: createjobrequest
      required:
      - company
      - position
      type: object
      properties:
        company:
          type: string
        position:
          type: string
      example:
        company: mongodb
        position: back-end developer
    updatejobrequest:
      title: updatejobrequest
      required:
      - company
      - position
      type: object
      properties:
        company:
          type: string
        position:
          type: string
      example:
        company: prime
        position: front-end developer
    loginrequest:
      title: loginrequest
      required:
      - email
      - password
      type: object
      properties:
        email:
          type: string
        password:
          type: string
      example:
        email: john@gmail.com
        password: john@gmail.com
  securitySchemes:
    httpBearer:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
security:
- httpBearer: []
tags:
- name: Misc
  description: ''
- name: Auth
  description: ''
- name: Jobs
  description: ''
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to unindent `/jobs/{id}` in line 90 by two spaces.